# Recovering Using a Continuous Archive Backup postgres

Tags: postgresql, docker

My use ["recovering Using a Continuous Archive Backup"](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/continuous-archiving.html) for postgres db, Base Backup and WAL Archiving Done, But there is a problem, Unfortunately, I can not perform recovery operations.
The things I did are:

> 1- Stop the server, if it's running
>
> 2- I remove the entire database

and ...
Now I'm really dumbfounded, And I do not know what to do, Please guide if anyone knows, And to get a back up, I've got a right path

Comment: Describe how exactly you performed the backup and how you archived the WAL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use "Postgres WAL Archiving", As follows:

```
1- Postgres WAL Archiving
2- Add Data to PostgreSQL
3- Testing Restore
4- Restore from WAL Archiving
```

Referance to the [link](https://github.com/anishnath/postgres)